# Objective C - Audio in Background With Red Indicatior

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

My app currently plays an mp3 audio file while the user is searching for another active user on the app.

In my app delegate, I ask for more background time to continue performing the search:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Background handler called. Not running background tasks anymore.");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
        self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

}
```

When the user sends the app to the background, the audio continues to play as the search algorithms continue to work.

However, I would like for there to be the red indicator bar across the top of the screen, similar to what you would see when a VOIP call is performing on an app in the background.

Is this possible?

Here is my audio player code in SearchView.m

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/searchTune.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];

NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];

[_audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: This is not possible as these are all system alerts which are not exposed to third party applications and would also add too many convoluted meanings to the notifications.

Comment: To be blunt, I did not understand the use case here. While searching why do you need to play the song. Also how much time your web service is taking to return the search result? If it is more than 2 to 3 seconds in good network condition, then try adding pagination after applying all the optimisation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible. No public API for that, iOS uses private API's for their internal use. It is called pulsating status bar.